# Xamarin: Xamarin Mac Agent shows limited connection

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio is connected to my Mac, but the Xamarin Mac Agent is showing limited connectivity (showing yellow but should be green). I am unable to run the app on Macbook, although I can start the simulator from Visual Studio.

Anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Make sure that both the version of Xamarin on the Macbook and the PC are the same version. Also check the output window for and change to the Build host log to see logged issues.

Comment: I am unable to find the xamarin on macbook. It was installed but now i cant find it.

Comment: It comes with Xamarin Studio. There isn't anything you need to launch separately.

Comment: I am re-installing xamarin studio on mac so that i have up to date version of xamarin.  Lets see if it help Thanks :)

Comment: Problem solved? how?

Comment: @diego Moreira Yes, your version of xamarin studio and Xamarin version of  visual studio should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Check Xamarin Logs (Open Logs via Visual Studio, Xamarin - Open Logs) or Zip Logs and extract it.

2 - The user that is performing SSH on mac needs to have read and write Access on Xcode Path.

3 - The Xcode path needs to be setup via Visual Studio Configuration.

Edit:

4 - If you still have issues, make sure both side of Xamarin (OSX and Windows) are same version. You can update Xamarin studio both on Mac and Windows to make sure.

Comment: I had the same problem about a few minutes ago. I disconnected my mac server and then connected again. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the visual studio make sure no process is running related to visual studio instance
2. On mac osX build machine quit applications xamarin studio/visual studio for mac and iphone emulators.
3. Clear the temporary data (%temp%) on your windows PC.
4. Reopen visual studio and connect to mac build agent, it will successfully connect and turn to green icon.